# values of the parameter $a$ for which the equation $2t^3-9t^2+30-a=0$ has $6$ distinct real solution

Tags: calculus

Let t be a real value satisfying $2t^3-9t^2+30-a=0$.then values of the parameter

$a$ for which the equation $\displaystyle x+\frac{1}{x}=t$ gives six real and distinct values of $x$.

Attempt: with the help of  $A.M\geq G.M\;,$ If

for  $x>0\;,$ Then $x+\frac{1}{x}\geq 2$ and If $x<0\;,$ Then $\displaystyle x+\frac{1}{x}\leq -2$

so we have  $|t|\geq 2$

Now for  $f(t) = 2t^3-9t^2+30-a$

with  Derivative test, We have $f'(t) = 6t^2-18t = 6t(t-3)$

and for Maximum and minimum ,  $f'(t) = 0\Rightarrow t=0,3$

and  $f''(t) = 12t-18,$ Now $f''(0) = -18$ and $f''(3) = 18$

So Here $t=0$ is a point of local Maximum and $t=3$ is a Point of Local Minimum.

and its graph is http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28t%29+%3D+2t%5E3-9t%5E2%2B30

for three distinct real values of $t\;,$ we have  $3<a<30$

is it right , if there is any error please help me how to go further, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it right , if there is any error please help me how to go further

No, it is not right.

You have to consider the condition $|t|\gt 2$.

Let $g(t)=2t^3-9t^2+30$. Then,
$$g(-2)=-22,\quad g(2)=10$$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

So, considering the graph with $g(0)=30$ and $g(3)=3$, we see that there are no $a$ such that $g(t)=a$ has three distinct real solutions where $|t|\gt 2$.